# heroku rack dependency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, bundler, rack

I am using `rack 1.2.3` from my git repo in the Gemfile

```
gem 'rack', :git => 'git://github.com/madhums/rack.git', :branch => 'aesthete'
```

Everything works fine locally. When I deploy to heroku, I get this error **You have already activated rack 1.1.0, but your Gemfile requires
rack 1.2.3. Consider using bundle exec. (Gem::LoadError)**

```
Starting process with command `thin -p 36127 -e development -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start
`/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:27:in
`block in setup': 

You have already activated rack 1.1.0, but your Gemfile requires rack 1.2.3
Consider using bundle exec. (Gem::LoadError)
```

I believe some other gem which heroku is using is dependent on rack 1.1.0?

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need add thin gem in your Gemfile. Maybe can works

```
gem 'thin'
```